# Migrate a VMWare guest system to a physical drive

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have been working on a project of mine on Ubuntu 16.04 which I installed on VMWare on Windows 10. Now due to RAM issues and lagging I want to migrate this virtual environment into a physical environment which I can dual boot with my Windows 10(so it can use the entire resources available). Is there a way to install Ubuntu using a snapshot from VMWare? If not, is there a way to migrate all my files and settings from VMWare into an existing Ubuntu installation?